# check if this DataReader field is a date

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a Web Service that connect in a DB, and return data in string format but I found one problem when there is a date.

Here my code.
I just need this check because the rest of code works..

```
Dim recordSet As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
'recordSet execution

Dim dataFormat As String
dataFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

While recordSet.Read()
   For i = 0 To count

      'Below the part of code i can't find a solution
      If TypeOf (recordSet(i)) Is TimeSpan Then
         'This is only a time like 09:12:52
      ElseIf TypeOf (recordSet(i)) Is Date Then
         If Format(recordSet(i)).ToString = dataFormat Then
            'This is just a date like 2018-10-11
         Else
            'This is a timestamp like 2019-03-12 10:00:52
         End If
      End If
      'End part

   Next i
End While
```

The problem is when it's the "date field" turn, vb.net automatically set it with 12:00:00 AM and the result is a timestamp but in DB i'm sure it's a date type:

```
"timestamp" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
"time" time(6),
"date" date
```

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to ensure what you think is happening is actually happening?

Comment: Your inner `If` statement is never going to work.  It's can't possibly.  The code doesn't even really make sense as it is. If you're relying on the value to tell you whether it is just date or date and time then you should be comparing its `TimeOfDay` property to `TimeSpan.Zero`.

Comment: Have you tried IsDate?

Comment: Yes of course. I created a table in my db to test types: If recordSet(i) is a time value like this: http://i.imgur.com/GohxQXw.png it goes on "Timespan" if. If recordSet(i) is a timestamp value like this: http://i.imgur.com/8py3euD.png it goes on "Date" if and in the else because it doesn't respect the format "YYYY-MM-DD". But if recordSet(i) is just a date (on db), vb.net automatically edit this value in a timestamp like this: http://i.imgur.com/8hqwzPB.png and if I make a GetType is actually a Date Time so it didn't work how i want: http://i.imgur.com/8I79Ku0.png